# Why are my polygons not opaque?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

A newbie to XNA here.  This is a followup to my previous [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6597/getting-a-black-scene-with-xna-what-am-i-doing-wrong) that showed me part of what I was doing wrong but I'm still not getting what I want.  I'm setting up a BasicEffect thus:

```
Effect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
Effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
Effect.Alpha = 1.0f;
Effect.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
Effect.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
```

and the draw loop:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, MaxDepth, 0);
```

All polygons are being rendered where and how I wish except they should be fully opaque and they aren't.  The actual image looks more like the various colors are being combined in a fashion I'm not sure about:

[image]

Comment: We could probably use a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the DepthStencilState and BlendState before drawing the object, and not when creating your Effect, just like this:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, MaxDepth, 0);
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;

DrawYourThings();
```

Comment: Thank you!   I figured it was something simple I was not understanding.